# How do I prevent users without admin access from saving a form with a certain status in faces

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces, facelets

I'm trying to prevent users without Administrative access from saving a form with the "complete" status selected, if it was not already selected (e.g. users are allowed to open up forms and make edits to their data, even if the status is set to complete, they just cannot initially mark their documents as complete).

The reason users are allowed to make changes to 'completed' documents is that the electronic record is just a reflection of a behinds the scenes work process. In order for an item to be marked as complete, several other processes have to have been completed. The information can be edited after the fact to account for errors in transcription or verbiage.

I'm thinking that it would be sufficient to just utilize an `onChange` event that re-selects the previous selection if a user tries to *change* the status to complete . I'm looking for an elegant way to do it, hopefully without storing the previous selection in a separate field on the page, as it is already stored elsewhere.
the `grantBacking.editGrant.statusCode`  is the saved/current status code for the form. Also, there are at least three different role types including just read access, 'Add', and 'Administrator'. Read - self explanatory, Add - Can make changes to the form but should not be able to complete a form, and Administrator - can make changes and can mark a form status as "complete".

This is what I have so far:

```
<t:panelGroup>
<sec:authorize ifNotGranted="ADMINISTRATOR">

    <h:selectOneMenu id="grantStatus" onchange="#checkGrantStatusPermissions(this,grantBacking.editGrant.statusCode)" onmouseover="Tip('#{msg_bundle.grant_status_help}')" value="#{grantBacking.editGrant.statusCode}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{grantBacking.grantSelectStatusForNonAdmin}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</sec:authorize>

<sec:authorize ifAnyGranted="ADMINISTRATOR">

    <h:selectOneMenu id="grantStatusForAdmin" onmouseover="Tip('#{msg_bundle.grant_status_help}')" value="#{grantBacking.editGrant.statusCode}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{grantBacking.grantSelectStatus}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</sec:authorize>

<sec:authorize ifAnyGranted="ADD">
<a4j:commandLink id="qsave2" render="@all" onmouseover="Tip('Click to quick save')" action="#{grantBacking.saveGrant}">
    <h:graphicImage title="Click this to quick save the grant/contract" style="border-style:none;" height="20px" width="15px" library="default" name="img/icons/disk.png" />
</a4j:commandLink>
</sec:authorize>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkGrantStatusPermissions(field, originalValue){
        if(originalValue.equalsIgnoreCase("complete")){
            return  
        }
        else{
            document.getElementByID(field).value = originalValue.value;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you not just remove "complete" from the list of options if those conditions are not met? If you don't like that approach you can also disable complete using the var & itemDisabled attributes of the selectItems tag.

Comment: I thought of that at first, but the form saves all of the fields if the user clicks 'save'. That means that if the status no longer shows "complete" when the user clicks save, the status will be changed.

Comment: Can you better describe what is the user allowed to do? If the status is already "complete" then why is a normal user allowed to edit it?

Comment: I added a paragraph in the middle of the question to address that. I guess I didn't say that only users with the 'Add' privilege can make the additions, so normal users with 'read' access cannot make changes.

Comment: with 'ajax' you can prevent all fields to be submitted

Comment: You're trying to prevent users from _saving_ a "completed" form. If you don't want them to save it, don't allow them to edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to the item being marked as complete you can disable the option by building your selectItems like so:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{grantBacking.grantSelectStatusForNonAdmin}" var="v"
    itemDisabled="#{grantBacking.shouldDisableOption(v)}"/>
```

If your version of the EL doesn't include the ability to pass parameters you can accomplish the same by using an inner class that holds your value, label, and has a parameterless method for shouldDisable.

When it comes to submitting a completed form if the user can't change it from Complete to some other status, then just make the selectMenu readonly. If they can, then your shouldDisable logic should return false in this case.

Doing something like this prevents the users from selecting known bad values and avoids you coding behavior that the users wouldn't expect leading to potential bug reports.